# Amazon Web Service RDS DB Engine Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm want to use Amazon Web Service RDS.
So I'm working on process for setting.

But when I choose DB engine version, 
there are two type(a, b) about 5.6.19.

Are there difference between two types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The a and b letter designations appear to indicate that the instance will be running the stated official release version plus bug fixes created or backported or otherwise applied by the RDS developers... So 5.6.19b would be the newer of those two.  The issues they address are explained here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.KnownIssuesAndLimitations

However, unless you have a specific reason not to, you should probably use the latest version available.